# Is it safe to use headphones with mono jacks into stereo jacks on a modern PC?

Tags: stereo, headphones, mono, computer, connector

If I understand correctly, plugging a mono jack into a stereo socket would short the right channel of the stereo to the ground.

Yet most audio amplifiers have a short detection/protection circuit in place to address that issue right?

So would that be safe to use the mono earphone on modern computers without risking burning up the right channel amplifier?

Comment: ive done things like that a thousand times, never hurt anything... Can't back it up in a good way cause to me it was never a question and never got to search about it. Can't really tell you what to do , but i never had problems with such connections

Comment: @frcake  thank you!  I did that many times too and never had problems, just that someone else I know had an anomaly of his right channel amp stopped working after he plugged the mono earbud into his pc...well, bad luck for him I guess.

Comment: Just as you have mentioned in your OP, it probably will be safe for modern stereo systems. However, it will not be ideal as you will only get the left channel audio signal to the connected headphones or speaker, as the right channel signal is shorted to GND.    Note that though the chances are very low,  with old electronics or badly designed circuits,  which aren't designed to cope with that shorting on the right channel, it could damage the amplifier.